# Getting an Unknown Provider Error for using angular-filter groupBy in my Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

This is the code my html page:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value)  in list.arrayofStuff | orderBy: 'order' |  groupBy: 'code' ">
```

In the Index.html I've imported the angular-filter:

```
<script src="lib/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

But for some reasong, I'm getting this error.

> ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter

Do i have to inject the angular-filter into my controller as well?
I'm using Ionic 1. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to include the angular-filter module in your apps dependencies.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

Source [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: Got this error when  I tried it:ionic.bundle.js:17917 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hospitalCare due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module  angular-filter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module ' angular-filter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=%20angular-filter

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS you don't import filters by including a script tag to them. Check out [this blog post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters) or [the AngularJS docs for setting up a custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

When creating the filter you first get a reference to your app module, and then you can just use the .filter method off of it. Specifying your module name here is what "registers" your filter with AngularJS.

```
angular.module('MyAppModule')
.filter('filterName', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    return input;
  };
})
```

Then in your controller you can use the filter like so:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'filterName', function($scope, filterName) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
  $scope.filteredGreeting = filterName($scope.greeting);

}]);
```

or in html:

```
{{ expression | filter }}
```

It also sounds like you might be using an external module. If some other developer on your team (or not on your team) gave you a module and didn't use MyAppModule (or whatever your module's name is) then you will need to import that module. You can check the [AngularJS docs on Modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for more info on this, but basically you declare the other dev's module in the array when you first create your project's module:

```
var app = angular.module("MyAppModule", ["otherDevsModule"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to use the angular-filter groupBy filter, not a custom one. https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby . I've included the module name 'angular-filter' in the angular.module, but that trows an error.

Comment: Ok, just run `npm install angular-filter` and replace above 'otherDevsModule' with 'angular.filter'.

Comment: Hi Jim, I've done that, so i have angular-filter in my /lib, but this si the error I get: ionic.bundle.js:17917 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module  angular.filter due to:

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I have it in my /lib". It is a public project that you can post a link to?

Comment: Sorry guy's, my silly silly mistake, left a space before angular " angular.filter". Thanks guy's appreciate your help

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! Please accept an answer if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim, but it was actually Chris Moody's answer that got it working. Thanks anyway though